# Prevent other threads access object during write

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Let's say i have an Object:

```
class Obj o{ 
  public int x;
  public int y;
}
```

and a thread calls the method:

```
update(Obj o, int x, int y){
  o.x = x;
  o.y = y;
}
```

How can I prevent that other threads have access to the fields of this object during the execution of 'update' and wait until the method is finished to read the data?

Comment: A simple solution is to use synchronized methods. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make the members of the Obj class private so you have control over their access.  Then, move the update() method inside the class and declare it synchronized.  Finally, create getX() and getY() methods inside the class to get the values and declare them synchronized as well.

Making all these methods members of the class and synchronizing them will ensure that they can't be run by different threads at the "same time".